# Draw line segments through vertically stacked points on a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a fairly large data set that is very similar to the following example:

```
a <-data.frame(x=sort(c(replicate(4,c(1:4,5:8,9:12,13:16,17:20,21:25)))),y=c(rnorm(100)),z=c(replicate(20,"a"),replicate(20,"b"),replicate(20,"c"),replicate(20,"d"),replicate(20,"e")))

# install and enable ggplot2, if necessary
# install.packages('ggplot2') 
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z)) + geom_point(size=3)
```

[image: example plot]

I would like to draw color-matched vertical line segments through each set of stacked points, but only through the points. abline() won't do the trick, in this case. I suspect that segments() or lines() need to be used, but I haven't a clue how to automate this process without manually entering each start/end point.

**UPDATE**

Revisiting the finalized code:

```
a <-data.frame(x=sort(c(replicate(4,c(1:4,5:8,9:12,13:16,17:20,21:24)))),y=c(rnorm(96)),z=c(replicate(24,"a"),replicate(24,"b"),replicate(24,"c"),replicate(24,"d")))

ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z)) + 
geom_point(size=3) +
stat_summary(aes(color=z), fun.ymin = min, fun.ymax = max, fun.y = max, show.legend = F)
```

Here's what happens when I change the point size to 1:

[image: size=1]

How do I control the size of all the points?

Comment: Yes, just between the outermost (upper/lower) points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stat_summary` (not sure why it's necessary to use `fun.y`)

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  stat_summary(fun.ymin = min, fun.ymax = max,
               aes(colour=z),
               fun.y = max)
```

If you want the legend to show points only you can add `show.legend=F` to `stat_summary()`

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies! Truly amazing! Here is a quick rendition of the actual data:[link]http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah165/stealing_zen/statplot_zpsmqdkfydm.png

Answer (score 2):

`geom_segment` can do this, but you need to pick out the points between which you want to draw segments, as `geom_segment` has a lot of required aesthetics (`x`, `y`, `xend`, `yend`). It's easiest to do this before plotting, and in this case, it's simplest to make a separate data.frame for the purpose. There are lots of ways to make such a data.frame, but using base R, you could do something like

```
maxes <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(a, a$z), function(s){s[which.max(s$y),]}))
mins <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(a, a$z), function(s){s[which.min(s$y),]}))
names(maxes) <- paste0(names(maxes), '_max')
names(mins) <- paste0(names(mins), '_min')
mm <- cbind(maxes, mins)
```

which is a little complicated, but if you're comfortable with `lapply`, not terrible. If you like `dplyr`, you can do the same thing with

```
library(dplyr)
maxes <- a %>% group_by(z) %>% slice(which.max(y))
mins <- a %>% group_by(z) %>% slice(which.min(y))
names(maxes) <- paste0(names(maxes), '_max')
names(mins) <- paste0(names(mins), '_min')
mm <- bind_cols(maxes, mins)
```

which is, perhaps, more intuitive. Either way, now we can use `mm` which looks like

```
  x_max    y_max z_max x_min     y_min z_min
1     4 1.212553     a     5 -2.582079     a
2     8 2.695793     b     8 -1.642280     b
3    11 1.980166     c    14 -1.526656     c
4    18 1.497085     d    20 -2.131925     d
5    23 1.867731     e    24 -1.260946     e
```

which we can use to plot `geom_segment`:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z)) + geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=x_max, y=y_max, xend=x_min, yend=y_min, col = z_max), data = mm)
```

resulting in a plot that looks like:

[image: plot with segments from max to min]

---

Alternately, if you're going for more of a rectangle look, you can use a similar approach (though you could, of course, use `geom_rect` or the like, as well):

```
segs <- data.frame(x = seq(2.5, 22.5, by = 5), 
                   ymax = tapply(a$y, a$z, max), 
                   ymin = tapply(a$y, a$z, min),
                   z = levels(a$z))

ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z)) + geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = ymax, xend = x, yend = ymin, 
                   col = z), alpha = 0.3, size = 33, data = segs, show.legend = FALSE)
```

which plots

[image: plot with wide transparent segments]

Comment: Those rectangular plot regions are beautiful! I can think of a lot of uses for that. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: `geom_point` and `stat_summary` size points differently for some reason. The good news is that you don't need `geom_point` if you use `fun.y = identity`, which tells `stat_summary` to plot all points. All together: `ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z)) + stat_summary(fun.ymin = min, fun.ymax = max, fun.y = identity, size = .1)`

Comment: A most elegant solution! Brother, I so appreciate the help! I'm trying like mad to make a deadline and you really came through...